# Why if "allParticipants == 0" and there are custom questions the message that appears is incorrect?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have the registration form below that:

- if "`allParticipants == 1`" it should appear the message: "`<p>Please fill all form fields. Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.</p>`" (this is working)
- else, if "`allParticipants == 0`" and there are no custom questions, that is "`$selectedRtype['questions']`" is `empty` it should appear the message "`<p>Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be send to "<b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b></p>`" (this is working)
- if "`allParticipants == 0`" and there are custom questions, that is, "`$selectedRtype['questions']`" is not `empty`, it shoud appear the message "`<p>Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.You only need to answer to the custom questions below.</p>`" (this is not working)

But its not working for the third scenario, for when "`if "allParticipants == 0`" and there are custom questions,"  the message that appears is "`<p>Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be send to "<b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b></p>`", but the message that should appear in this case is "`<p>Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.You only need to answer to the custom questions below. </p>`".

Do you know where is the issue?

// form part where are the conditions:

```
<form method="post" id="step1formfree" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @if (!is_null($allParticipants) && is_int($allParticipants))
        @if($allParticipants == 1)
            <p>Please fill all form fields. Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.</p>
        @else
            // if there are no custom questions the message should be only "Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be sent to"
            @if(is_null($selectedRtype['questions']))
                <p>Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be sent to
                    <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b></p>
            // if the user selected in the previous page tickets that have associated custom questions the message should be "Your tickets will be send to....You only need to answer to the custom questions below."
            @else
                <p>Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.
                    You only need to answer the custom questions below.
                </p>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endif
```

The `{{dd($selectedRtype['questions'])}}` shows:

```
Collection {#236 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

// complete form

```
<form method="post" id="step1formfree" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @if (!is_null($allParticipants) && is_int($allParticipants))
        @if($allParticipants == 1)
            <p>Please fill all fields. Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.</p>
        @elseif(!is_null($selectedRtype['questions']))
           <p>Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.You only need to answer to the custom questions below.</p>
        @else
           <p>Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be send to "<b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b></p>
        @endif

        <span id="userData" data-name="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" data-surname="{{ auth()->user()->surname }}"></span>

        @foreach($selectedRtypes as $k => $selectedRtype)
            //{{dd($selectedRtype)}}
            @foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $val)
                @if($allParticipants == 1)
                    <h6>Participant - {{$val}} - {{$k}}</h6>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="fill_auth_info{{ $val }}" data-id="{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}"name="fill_with_auth_info">
                        <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="fill_auth_info{{ $val }}">
                            <span class="mr-auto">Fill with auth user info.</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="name{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                        <input type="text"  id="name{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="surname{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="surname{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                    </div>
                    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                                   class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                            <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <input type="hidden" value="foo" name="participant_name[]"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="bar" name="participant_surname[]"/>
                @endif
                <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]" value="{{ $selectedRtype['id'] }}"/>
            @endforeach
                    <div class="form-group">
            @if ($allParticipants == 0)
                @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                               class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                               value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
    <input type="submit" href="#step2"
           id="goToStep2Free" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job showing the dump for questions: `{{dd($selectedRtype['questions'])}}`.

How about simplfying the if-check (and `dd`) to: `@if( $selectedRtype->questions->count())`?  This might make it a little easier to debug/read for you as well as closer to what you are trying to say in human terms.  Take a look at:

[Laravel Docs for count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-count)

Remember, with your `dd` above, you've seen that an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection is always returned, even when there are no results. You are basically checking that $x = new stdClass; if ($x) { ... } which will *always return true* (or always false for a is_null check).

It may be possible that the if check is looking at a different value than when you dd -- in theory you are 100% correct - based on the collection being returned, it should be false in the is_null check, but it's not.  I think if you check for the count or `! $selectedRtype->questions->isEmpty()`... or even `$selectedRtype->questions->first()`, it may bring to light the issue.

** NOTE - the complete form and the section are different.  The section's code has the if-check for questions.  It appears the 'Complete Form' only checks for allParticipants.  Is it possible that you've just not included the code in the final form?

Comment: Thanks, but using "$selectedRtype->questions..." shows always "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: @joW - take a look at my edit with the NOTE -- possible you've just not copied the full code into the final form?

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the complete form.

Comment: Please can you try with the exact code as in the section.  The elseif is going to cause problems (not allow the 3rd check to be true because it is already passed for $allParticipants == 1)  IE it may never show the 'Is not necessary additional info.'

Comment: With that code it appears the wrong message "           <p>Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be send to "<b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b></p>" instead of "<p>Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.You only need to answer to the custom questions below. </p>".

Comment: And {{dd(is_null($selectedRtype['questions']))}} shows what?

Comment: It appears false.

Comment: Then the code in the section "// form part where are the conditions:" has to work.  Suggest you copy exactly this into your final code.  If it is still displaying the wrong message, do some dds inside each part of the if-checks to see where it is failing.  Your code is correct (in the section), and the dd shows the if-check is correct.  I am starting to wonder about a typo - I'd try the dds in the various places to see where it is passing/failing the checks.